# Is it possible to see icons with text in app bar?

Tags: 8.1, icons

If you are new to windows phone, you don't exactly know which icon do what action. So you have to tap on `...` (context menu) every time.

Is it possible to change this?

For example:

1. only icons (default)
2. only text
3. icons + text

Or do you know if is this planned in the future? I coudn't find any info on the web nor in the official [Microsoft Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

---

[image: text below icons in app bar]

So result will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible and as far as I can tell from the Windows 10 Preview this is not about to change. I'd recommend posting your suggestion to the [Windows Phone UserVoice site](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com).